# :empty style not being removed when content added in through javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've made a quick fiddle to demonstrate this issue https://jsfiddle.net/chfj1jLq/2/

This code works fine in Chrome/Firefox but not in IE11. I have a :hover selector on my div but i want to override it if the previous div is empty. The css i've written does just this but for some reason in IE the :empty style doesn't get removed until the first time you hover over the div, then it seems to trigger.

```
.A{
    background:blue;
}

.B:hover{
    background: green;
}

.A:empty + .B{
    background:black;
}
```

Comment: This behaves fine in IE11 for me

Comment: Really, mines specifically version 11.0.96, not sure if that helps. So you click the button and the black div immediately turns red? Or do you need to first hover over the div for it to trigger?